# mongodb replica sets read locking

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, database

We have a Mongo Replica Set with three nodes in three datacenters. Two of them with data and the other one is an arbitrer

We are doing stressful writes in the primary with almost 100% of locking so we are doing the reads in the replica node (secondary). Our problem is that the reads are slow too in the secondary due to those writes.

Are we missing anything?

Comment: I think a better explanation is here at "How does concurrency affect secondaries?" section: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-does-concurrency-affect-secondaries Just in case someone's looking for a better clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> We are doing stressful writes in the primary with almost 100% of locking so we are doing the reads in the replica node (secondary). Our problem is that the reads are slow too in the secondary due to those writes.

When you perform a write to the primary, that write also has to be performed on the secondary. So the secondary is doing the same work as the primary.

So if you have 100% locking on the primary, you have 100% locking on the secondary.

Moving reads to the secondary probably won't help because your IO on the primary is probably completely locked so it can't keep up.

Run `iostat` and `top` and figure out where the bottleneck is. It's likely that you'll need power, but it may just be an indexing problem.

Comment: thanks, locks are kind of obligatory because is a heavy write schema. We have "solved" the problem doing sharding thorough cores in the same instances. We know it isn't recommended but we have read is a solutions for this kind of problem and early tests are proving it.

My question now is: is there any alternative to Mongo or which is the best dbsystem to manage this kind of concurrency? (heavy and stressful writes always/reads)

Comment: Redis is probably worth investigating. It makes a different set of trade-offs, you'll be limited to Key-Value. But the performance numbers tend to be very good on Redis with less CPU required for each read / write. Riak may also be a reasonable alternative, again based on Key/Value being a limiting factor. I would start with Redis as it is the most likely candidate.

Comment: One other thing to consider is that your reads are going to a secondary in another data center. This will likely cause those reads to be very slow as those reads are traveling a long distance.

Comment: We need a query reach database, so key-value doesn't seems like a solution for a problem. About the data centers, we are doing the reads using the shell in the secondary server directly. They are slow when we are writing but if we stop writing, then the reads are fast.

Comment: This is our iostat  while the writing process so it doesn't seem a IO problem despite of the avgrq-sz value...no? thanks http://pastebin.com/DYUb8rbV

Comment: Your `iostat` says `wkB/s: 55420.00`. That means that you are writing 55MB/s. What type of hardware are you using? Good server drives do about 100-120 MB/S, but if you are on virtual hardware that may be all that you get. Also, some detail is missing on the `iostat`. Your utilization % can't be zero if you're pushing 50MB/s, that typically means virtual hardware.

Comment: I think it is a common setup for mongodb.

Mongo is running under ec2 m2.x2large: 16 ebs in RAID10 (we also tried with 8ebs with same results)

34.2 GB of memory
13 EC2 Compute Units (4 virtual cores with 3.25 EC2 Compute Units each)
850 GB of instance storage
64-bit platform
I/O Performance: High
API name: m2.2xlarge

The writing process is running under c1.xlarge

7 GB of memory
20 EC2 Compute Units (8 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each)
1690 GB of instance storage
64-bit platform
I/O Performance: High
API name: c1.xlarge

Where do you think the bottleneck is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write heavy systems under Mongo tend to have two major bottle necks: IO and the single write lock. MongoDB does not have parallel writes. Check out the `mongostat` tool and see how many writes you are getting. How does this compare to what you are expecting? How many writes are you expecting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7213/discussion-between-aartiles-and-gates-vp)